# How to connect to MySQL Database through JDBC driver using Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I tried using JayDebeApi in this case but getting error as "ImportError: No module named JayDeBeApi"

And I want to connect to MySql Db, what steps should i follow?

Please help
Below is the basic test i am trying

```
*** Settings ***

Library          DatabaseLibrary


*** Variables ***
${DB_CONNECT_STRING} =  'org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.Driver', 'jdbc:avatica:remote:url=http://135.197.226.119:30000;serialization=protobuf', ['admin','admin']


*** Test Cases *** 
Connecting
     Connect

     @{queryResults}  Query  select * from table persons
     log to console  @{queryResults}

     Disconnect

*** Keywords ***
Connect
      connect to database using custom params    JayDeBeApi    ${DB_CONNECT_STRING}


Disconnect
      disconnect from database
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the "JayDeBeApi" module installed? The error says no, here's how to install it:

```
pip install JayDeBeApi
```

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed Robot Framework [DatabaseLibrary](https://franz-see.github.io/Robotframework-Database-Library/) is compatible with [python database modules](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DatabaseInterfaces#General_Purpose_Database_Systems) that support DB-API 2.0. In the earlier linked list [JayDeBeApi](https://pypi.org/project/JayDeBeApi/) is not mentioned but it seems to support the DB-API 2.0 specification. So, on paper it should support it. However, it is not installed with DatabaseLibary, you'll need to add it yourself.

On the linked list there is dedicated support for several [Pure Python MySQL modules](https://wiki.python.org/moin/MySQL) mentioned. For this reason it is a little beyond me why you'd want to prefer JayDeBeApi with it's java dependency if you can use a pure python module. However, all of these modules require an additional installation as well. Even though they are pure python, they are not part of the out-of-the-box python installation.